# SQL - insert row values from second column ( to new table as column data)

Tags: sql

While having the result set:

```
Name        Values

PRODUCT                         FILLER888
LOT_NUMBER                  CG 00063 0
SHIFT_SUPERVISOR        covaliu l
KGH_ALL_SET 90
KGH_ALL_REAL    133.183883666992
KGH_F1_SET  90
KGH_F1_REAL 133.183883666992
K_F1    33
SCREW_RPM_SET   400
SCREW_RPM_REAL  399.452606201172
TORQUE  19.6692142486572
CURRENT 71.0029983520508
KW_KG   0.0553370267152786
KW  7.36999988555908
MELT_PRESSURE   0
MELT_TEMPERATURE    140
PV1 141
SP1 140
PV2 160
SP2 160
PV3 160
SP3 160
PV4 160
SP4 160
PV5 160
SP5 160
PV6 150
SP6 150
PV7 150
SP7 150
PV8 154
SP8 150
PV9 150
SP9 150
PV10    160
SP10    160
PV11    180
SP11    180
```

I would like into a second table which is defined as the rows of the 1st:

```
CREATE TABLE #ZSK402temp 
(
 PRODUCT varchar(25),
LOT_NUMBER varchar(25),
SHIFT_SUPERVISOR varchar(25), 
KGH_ALL_SET decimal, 
KGH_ALL_REAL decimal, 
KGH_F1_SET decimal, 
KGH_F1_REAL decimal, 
K_F1 decimal, 
SCREW_RPM_SET decimal, 
SCREW_RPM_REAL decimal, 
TORQUE decimal, 
[CURRENT] decimal, 
KW_KG  decimal, 
KW decimal, 
MELT_PRESSURE decimal, 
MELT_TEMPERATURE decimal, 
PV1 decimal, 
SP1 decimal, 
PV2 decimal, 
SP2 decimal, 
PV3 decimal, 
SP3 decimal, 
PV4 decimal, 
SP4 decimal, 
PV5 decimal, 
SP5 decimal, 
PV6 decimal, 
SP6 decimal, 
PV7 decimal, 
SP7 decimal, 
PV8 decimal, 
SP8 decimal, 
PV9 decimal, 
SP9 decimal, 
PV10 decimal, 
SP10 decimal, 
PV11 decimal, 
SP11 decimal
 )
```

To insert the values from the 1st table as column data in the second table.

Any help is kindly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up some examples using SQL's `PIVOT` function. This will swap rows into columns to match the new table.

Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: pivot is powerfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table2 (SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Comment: Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition